# How does Spine.js generate unique IDs?

Tags: javascript, spine.js

Maybe I'm missing it but I'm not seeing where Spine.js generates unique ids for newly created records.

An example of this is clicking 'New Contact' in the Spine Contacts example (http://spine-contacts.herokuapp.com) and seeing the id in the url.

If you can explain how and include the line numbers from the source, that would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on their code from github [spine.js](https://github.com/maccman/spine.todos/blob/master/lib/spine.js) the following function does the guid generation:

```
guid = function() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r, v;
        r = Math.random() * 16 | 0;
        v = c === 'x' ? r : r & 3 | 8;
        return v.toString(16);
    }).toUpperCase();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Looks like the guid function was removed in the most recent version of Spine.  Explains why I wan't seeing it in the current github source.